# How to remove a part of string using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am comparing  file names in a folder ,I want to remove some part of string and check whether name exists or not

Here is my file name :

```
file1Name:AB-05012_MM-AB_585859_01 
file2Name:AB-05012_MM-AB_732320_01-1
```

Now i want to compare the string only till

```
AB-05012_MM-AB_732320_01 ignore '-1'
```

Here is my logic

```
if (file1Name.equals(file2Name.contains(""))){
  list.add(file1Name);           
}
```

Comment: Not enough info.  Do you only want to modify file names that end in `-1`?  Or `-` and a digit?  Or `-` and any character?  Or `-` and more than one character?  What characters do you want to check for following the `-`?  Or do you want to look for `-` followed by a digit in the middle of the name?  Can anything follow the `-1`?  If so, what?

Comment: Can you post example search terms and matching/non-matching filenames?

Comment: I have two folder which contains xml files & other contains .cgm files, Now Both the files have almost same name ,the .cgm files have extra '-00'

Comment: For each xml we have one or more .cgm files in the folder ,It is like abc.xml has abc-01,abc-02,abc-03

Comment: Now i want to check the name and add the all the .cgm files to a list

Comment: Please check i have edited

Answer (score 1):

When you know there is an extra character in second file name then why not using

```
fileName2.startsWith ( fileName1)
```

or

```
int indexOfDot = fileName1.lastIndexOf(".");
fileName2.startsWith ( fileName1.subString( 0, indexOfDot)
```

But this is very specific to your problem.  or for the cases where
`fileName2 = fileName1 + any character or digit`

Comment: No i have to check for different file names

Comment: Until unless you put more light on your problem, none will be able to give you the suitable solution

Comment: I have two folder which contains  xml files & other contains .cgm files, Now Both the files have almost same name ,the .cgm files have  extra '-00'

Comment: For each xml we have one or more .cgm files in the folder ,It is like abc.xml has abc-01,abc-02,abc-03

Comment: Now i want to check the name and add the all the .cgm files to a list

Comment: so that means you want all files which have `abc` in them ? Same I mentioned **`fileName2.starts with ( "abc")`**

Comment: Yes ,Exactly but i have to ignore last part

Comment: If i print XMLName.substring(0, indexOfDot)   I am getting XX-05012_XX-XX_732320_06.x

Comment: It should not. please post your fileName. May be then I can help you. Otherwise i tested this code for normal files. Here you may be missing normal string manipulation but what you need to understand is the logic. Can't this solution solve your problem ?

Comment: it is validating but when i add the file to list ,I am  getting Exception (null)

Comment: I don't any code for adding file or fileName to list. So update your code

Comment: You may not have initialised your list. Please post your whole code and error log as this is no way related to question you have asked so far

Comment: Got it Buddy...Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String myStr = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("-1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

if your file name is same length:

```
if (file1Name.equals(file2Name.substring(0,24))){
 //if same to some  task              
}
```

else:

```
if (file1Name.equals(file2Name.substring(0,file2Name.lastIndexOf('-')))){
 //if same to some  task              
}
```

And I think the second solution better.